# wxPython - Redrawing Error when replacing wxFrame's Panel

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm creating a small wxPython utility for the first time, and I'm stuck on a problem.

I would like to add components to an already created frame. To do this, I am destroying the frame's old panel, and creating a new panel with all new components.

1: Is there a better way of dynamically adding content to a panel?

2: Why, in the following example, do I get a a strange redraw error in which in the panel is drawn only in the top left hand corner, and when resized, the panel is drawn correctly?
(WinXP, Python 2.5, latest wxPython)

Thank you for the help!

```
    import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'TimeTablr')


        #Variables
        self.iCalFiles = ['Empty', 'Empty', 'Empty']
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.layoutElements()        


    def layoutElements(self):
        self.panel.Destroy()
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        #Buttons
        self.getFilesButton = wx.Button(self.panel, 1, 'Get Files')
        self.calculateButton = wx.Button(self.panel, 2, 'Calculate')
        self.quitButton = wx.Button(self.panel, 3, 'Quit Application')

        #Binds
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Quit, id=3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.getFiles, id=1)

        #Layout Managers
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        #Panel Contents
        self.ctrlsToDescribe = []
        self.fileNames = []
        for iCalFile in self.iCalFiles:
            self.ctrlsToDescribe.append(wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1))
            self.fileNames.append(wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, iCalFile))

        #Add Components to Layout Managers
        for i in range(0, len(self.ctrlsToDescribe)):
            hboxtemp = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            hboxtemp.AddStretchSpacer()
            hboxtemp.Add(self.fileNames[i], 1, wx.EXPAND)
            hboxtemp.AddStretchSpacer()
            hboxtemp.Add(self.ctrlsToDescribe[i], 2, wx.EXPAND)
            hboxtemp.AddStretchSpacer()
            vbox.Add(hboxtemp)

        finalHBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        finalHBox.Add(self.getFilesButton)
        finalHBox.Add(self.calculateButton)
        finalHBox.Add(self.quitButton)

        vbox.Add(finalHBox)
        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Show()


    def Quit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def getFiles(self, event):
        self.iCalFiles = ['Example1','Example1','Example1','Example1','Example1','Example1']
        self.layoutElements()
        self.Update()



app = wx.App()
MainFrame()
app.MainLoop()
del app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I beleive the Sizer will let you insert elements into the existing ordering of them. That would probably be a bit faster.

2) I don't see the behavior you're describing on OSX, but at a guess, try calling self.Layout() before self.Show() in layoutElements?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the panel would be squished into the upper-right corner. I solved it by calling `panel.Fit()`.

In your example, you should call `self.panel.Fit()` after `self.panel.SetSizer(vbox)`